# Как остановить выполнение скрипта через промежуток времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция, для динамического рендеринга HTML. Запускаю эту функцию с помощью

```
setInterval(getAndRenderTasks, 2500)
```

Все прекрасно работает и каждые 2,5 я "перерисовываю" данные полученные от сервера, без перезагрузки страницйы. Но проблема в том что setInterval() исполняется при запуске через 2,5с и на этот интервал времени мне нужно подставить иконочку с loader'ом

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать наиболее простым и "коробочным" способом? Мне очень важно сохранить переносимость между платформами поддерживающими HTML5

Лоадер нужен только при первой загрузке страницы, до тех пор пока первый раз не выполнится моя функция

Comment: Так в чем именно вопрос: "как остановить выполнение скрипта" или "как подставить иконочку"?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при загрузке страницы и до первого исполнения _getAndRenderTasks_ нужно повесить loader? Не совсем ясно, что, собственно, вы остановить то хотите =))

Comment: @Mr. Brightside
вы правильно поняли :)

Comment: Поставьте нужную иконку в разметку по умолчанию как исходную, потом просто функцией её затрёте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При первой загрузке страницы ваш лоадер должен уже быть на странице (т.е. в разметке HTML), например:

```
<div id="YOUR_DYNAMIC_CONTENT">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

И внутри вашей функции getAndRenderTasks нужно добавить что-то вроде:

```
$('.loader').remove();
```

Либо, как я понимаю, у вас идет ajax запрос, по завершении которого вы можете сделать что-то вроде:

```
$('#YOUR_DYNAMIC_CONTENT').html(RESULT_FROM_AJAX);
```

Последняя строчка так же удалит ваш лоадер.

В общем суть в том, что лоадер уже есть на странице, а после первого запроса - удаляется.

Либо, если нужно добавлять лоадер при каждом запросе - рекомендую ознакомиться с ajax методом - beforeSend.

Comment: Работает! Отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Если правельно понял , то в начале надо покозать лоудер:

```
var flag = 0 ;
var intV = setInteval(function(){
    // сюда код для показа лоудера
    if(flag)
    {
     clearInterval(intV);
    } 
    },2500)

function getAndRenderTasks()
{
 // пишем в конце функции
 flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: а лоадер только для 1 загрузки)

Comment: так я понял по вопросу

Comment: @ddeadlink

да, лоадер нужен только при первой загрузке страницы, до тех пор пока первый раз не выполнится моя функция

Comment: @ElectroGirl проверьте мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
    // сюда код для показа лоудера
    setTimeout(function(){

      // лоадер хайд
      // запуск твоей функции
    },2500)
```